# How to check if one collection only contains elements from another collection?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to see if my source collection contains values which can only be from a 2nd collection.

For example.

```
Valid data collection: 1, 2, 5 

Source Collection | Result
-----------------------------------------
<empty>           | true
1                 | true
1, 2              | true
1, 2, 5           | true
1, 5              | true
3                 | false (3 is illegal)
1, 3              | false (3 is illegal)
1, 2, 555         | false (555 is illegal)
```

So it's like .. if my source collection has some values .. then the values can only exist if they are contained in the *other* collection.

Urgh. hard to explain :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like

```
var allInCollection = src.All(x => valid.Contains(x));
```

Or if you prefer a loop-based approach:

```
bool result = true;
foreach(var e in src) 
{
    if (!valid.Contains(e)) result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `LINQ` `Except` To check if any of the element in the collection is *not* in the other collection.

For example:

```
var a = new List<int>() {1,2,5};
var b = new List<int>() {1,3};
var c = b.Except(a);
if (c.Any()){ //then it is wrong, some items of b is not in a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sourceCollection.All(num => validDataCollection.Contains(num))
```

Comment: Try to format your code next time, I did it for you this time.